# Javascript код в представлении Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2

Правильно ли размещать javascript-код в вьюшках где лежит PHP код или его надо размещать где то в другом месте?

Comment: .......по-вкусу

Comment: @АлексейШиманский дело в том что если в файле с вьшкой обычный js код проблем нет. Стоит туда добавить jquery код то он не работает. Я подсматрел на английском SO там подобное дело помещают внутрь heredoc переменной  которую потом выводят особым образом. вот тут посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147872/how-can-i-use-jquery-with-yii2

Comment: Надо наверное `jquery` включить пораньше. например в `AppAsset` добавить опцию `public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD]; public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\widgets\PjaxAsset'
    ];`

Answer (score 2):

Более правильный способ - с использованием asset с указанием зависимостей: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#asset-dependencies. Можно, конечно, подключать и напрямую, если сами скрипты небольшие, но уникальные на каждую вьюшку, например, вот так:

$this->registerJs('console.log("TEST");', yii\web\View::POS_END);

Comment: спасибо, непонятно только одно, зачем столько трудностей если можно было бы просто написать jquery код внутри обычных `<script> тегов`

Comment: Assets используются управления зависимостями и правильного порядка подключения js файлов и подключения скриптов в нужных местах. Например у вас для админки используется один ассет, а для главной страницы другой, а для внутренних - третий. Вам тогда вместо кучи скриптов с зависимостями достаточно будет на странице или в layout прописать 2 строчки: use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
AppAsset::register($this);

Comment: @MaseRus php неплохо парсит файлы. Можно было бы при генерации assets ов просто проанализировать js код. Но видимо разработчики выбрали другой путь. Спасибо за комментарий

Comment: Когда у тебя будет проект, где только одних вьюшек 20мб, будешь очень зол, встречая тэги js. Сложно поддерживать, сложно отыскивать и просто ужас, когда возникает конфликт. Используя ассеты, достаточно посмотреть в дебагер.